# how to switch a nested list to a array

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering how to combine two array of different shape to a new array but not change the original shape because the reshape information is import to future process. For example, I have two array (after feeding with data):

a: with shape (4950,40,10)
b: with shape (4950,64)

As we know, we can easily to use a list `c.append(a,b)` to get a nested one. So how could we do it using array?

Thanks.

Comment: May be you mean `c = [a, b]`. In Python `list.append` accepts only one parameter, not two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `numpy` array is a **regular** matrix where for example all rows must have the same length. You cannot build a `numpy` array shaped like the nested-list python structure:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [[4, 5],
  [6, 7]]]
```

the `.shape` member of a numpy array is a tuple of integers and for example `(9, 3, 7)` means a three-dimensional grid of `9×3×7` scalar values, you cannot have elements that are differently shaped `numpy` arrays.

For example if `m` is a `numpy` array where `m.shape == (9, 3, 7)` then `m[i]` is a `numpy` (sub)array with shape `(3, 7)` for any `i` value.

You can however just pass `[a, b]` around (i.e. a **python list** containing two differently shaped `numpy` arrays).

Comment: so if i have a list called c=[a,b], how can i get the same index in a and b, for example, i want to get [a[0:3],b[0:3]] ,can i use c[:][0:3],i tried this method but it does't work

Comment: @hunter: no... Python list do not support the broadcast features of `numpy` arrays... you have to write explicitly things like `[x[0:3] for x  in c]`. Note also that slicing for list makes a shallow copy and doesn't create a view on the original data... i.e. after `a=[1,2,3,4]; b = a[1:]` the statement `b[0] = 9` will not alter `a` like what would happen with `numpy` arrays.